# Choppy USB mice on just one of USB ports

Tags: 11.04, usb, mouse

I've got Lenovo b560 laptop with latest, properly updated Kubuntu on it (11.04 natty, kernel 2.6.38-8-generic). It has three USB2.0 ports onboard. I usually plug a mouse into one of them (I've got 3 different mice - in office, at home and for when on the go).

Sometimes, usually after laptop awakening from sleep, the mouse still works but cursor movements are choppy, as if the processor was extremely loaded (it's usually not). I found that if I re-plug the mouse cord into the other USB port, it works just fine. If I plug it back to problematic port, it is still choppy and remains choppy until next boot.

Of course I want my mice to always work fine. Problem is: I cannot reproduce this behavior for sure, it happens sporadically but regularly. I use different USB ports (problem has ever happened on each of them since), I use different mice (each has failed me this way at least once), I cannot generally find what exactly is going wrong and why plugging to different port fixes the mouse instantly.

So I'd like to hear at least clues where to look at, what to try to identify my problem.

A bit of update: while beginning this post, I had the issue once again. I have just replugged the mouse back to problematic port and it is not recognized at all. On the other port it works smoothly.

Comment: suggestion - have a look in your BIOS settings - if you have a "legacy USB support" option, try turning it on or off.

Comment: @fossfreedom thanks, most probably I do, so I'll try on the next boot. What does 'legacy' mean in technical terms, btw, what exactly can it change in the interacting with mice (any reading appreciated, I'm technical guy)?

Comment: try this thread as to a definition of legacy usb.  Another suggestion - you might like to consider trying the 2.6.39 kernel (search for that in AskUbuntu) http://help.wugnet.com/windows/USB-Legacy-BIOS-ftopict606120.html

Comment: Please also report your dmesg log file by running this command: `grep -i usb /var/log/dmesg` I'd like to see if the usb ports are being thrown off. It's happened before when hardware failure and shorts happen.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a hardware problem? There are several USB port problems reported on different Lenovo models, see for example the links listed on [their user forum](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Value-line/Yet-another-Lenovo-USB-port-problem/td-p/56802).